# Can I use canonical URL on the same page it links to?

Tags: url, seo, canonical-link

I want to ask about canonical URL. Lets assume this URL structure:

```
/category_A/page1
/category_B/page1
/category_C/page1
```

Simply put, there are multiple URLs that display the same content. But only /category_A/page1 is original(canonical) page. My question is if it have any impact(bad/good/neutral) considering SEO if I will have canonical URL pointing to /category_A/page1 placed in this same page /category_A/page1 ?

The reason for this is, that its much easier to just put canonical URL into head of every page than to trying find out in which page it is not needed (its the same page as canonical one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just do it

you described the perfect use case for the canonical tag. the canonical tag is a kind of failsafe against wrong URLs (or URLs with unnecessary parameters). so it's good to have it even on the page with the URL the canonical points to.