# can a web page have itself as canonical url?

Tags: html, seo, canonical-link

Let's say I have the same HTML page accessible with two distinct urls:

```
https://aaaa.mydomain.com/page/page.html

https://bbbb.mydomain.com/page/page.html
```

The first one is the "true" one, so I would want to use the canonical url.

My question: is it correct that the page https://aaaa.mydomain.com/page/page has in the code the canonical link to itself? i.e.:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://aaaa.mydomain.com/page/page.html" />
```

Comment: I just found that maybe it's duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231419/can-i-use-canonical-url-on-the-same-page-it-links-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Yoast it's a good practice, because every string appended to URL (like `?utm-src=xyz`) would be ignored.

[Source](https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/#self-referencing)